# SOLR schema.xml for string field LIKE%

Tags: java, search, solr

How to get values in SOLR for strings like in SQL `LIKE%`

For example I have these strings:

- `a` - 0 results
- `as` - 0 results
- `asd` - 0 results
- `asdd` - 15 results

How to configure this in `schema.xml`?

I tried to add `sortMissingLast="true"` but it still does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want to search from the front, letter by letter [a Edge N-Gram Tokenizer](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Tokenizers#Tokenizers-EdgeN-GramTokenizer) would do what you want. To decrease index-size I would furthermore add [a Lower Case Filter](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Filter+Descriptions#FilterDescriptions-LowerCaseFilter) to the analyzer.

You will need a custom `fieldType` - see below - which you will then need to use on the field of your choice of your document.

```xml
<fieldType name="my_sql_like" class="solr.TextField">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.EdgeNGramTokenizerFactory"
               minGramSize="4" maxGramSize="10"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

The interesting attributes here are

- **minGramSize** - how many characters does the user input require at least to make a match; as you want `asdd` to be the first search to generate a hit, I suggest to use `4`. More formally this defines the smallest size of a word/word fragment. If a word is smaller than this value, it will **not** make it into the index and thus not be searchable.
- **maxGramSize** - how much of each word will be placed in the index, as maximum; 10 is just a best bet; this depends on how long the words in your text is and/or how long the search input of your users is